# How to divide two Prometheus Counters

Tags: prometheus, metrics, promql

I have two metrics, Counters to be precise, lets say they are called

- NumberOfVisitors
- NumberOfLogins

In grafana I would like to plot is the number-of-logins divided by the number of visitors (or the other way around) over time. So I tried

```
rate(NumberOfLogins) / rate(NumberOfVisitors)
```

but this results in an error

> Error executing query: invalid parameter 'query': parse error at char
>   46: expected type range vector in call to function "rate", got instant
>   vector

I'm not sure what all that means. Hopefully something like this is possible. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Side note: `rate(NumberOfLogins) / rate(NumberOfVisitors)` is a valid query for [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html). See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#implicit-query-conversions) for details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rate function expect a range vector, for example:

```
rate(NumberOfLogins[5m])
```

That means to calcualte the rate within the last 5 minutes at each time point. You can change the `5m` to other time range.

Therefore this would fit you need:

```
rate(NumberOfLogins[5m]) / rate(NumberOfVisitors[5m])
```